# How do I preg_match for words in Hebrew

Tags: php, preg-match

I need a function that matches full words in hebrew in php.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers,

The one that works for me is preg_match("/^\p{Hebrew}+$/u", "שלום");

Answer (score 8):

Try this regular expression describing [Unicode character properties](http://docs.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
/\p{Hebrew}+/u
```

Comment: @Haim Bender: You need to set the *u* modifier.

Comment: Where is the `\p{Hebrew}` shortcut described? I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your source data is UTF-8 encoded

```
$input = "ט״סת תעסתינג O״ת סOמע העברעו תעחת";

preg_match_all( "/[\\x{0590}-\\x{05FF}]+/u", $input, $matches );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $matches );
echo '</pre>';
```

Yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ט״סת
            [1] => תעסתינג
            [2] => ״ת
            [3] => ס
            [4] => מע
            [5] => העברעו
            [6] => תעחת
        )

)
```

I based the range of 0590 through 05FF on [this Unicode chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0590.pdf) (edit: found more good hebrew/unicode info [here](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hebrew.html)).  I used [this](http://www.iosart.com/nlp/heb_enc_dec.html) to generate my sample input.  Since I don't know hebrew I can't actually verify that the matched output is valid.

You may need to tweak it but hopefully this gets you headed in the right direction.

Comment: i just need to check if a string is one single word in Hebrew, do I need to specify start and end of string in the regex? How can I implement this?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that would work - again I'm not going to pretend to understand the grammar of Hebrew.

Comment: @PeterBailey It is possible to use it in my php script? http://www.iosart.com/nlp/heb_enc_dec.html